# XHR throws errors that can't be catched

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm using the [XHR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr) lib on npm to make ajax requests on the client-side of a JS application. My code looks like this:

```
xhr({uri: "http://foo"},function (err, resp, body){
    if (err) ...
    else ...
});
```

Weirdly, even though I'm treating the errors on the callback, XHR still throws error messages such as `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()`. Since those messages are thrown by callback, I can't catch them. **How can I disable XHR's error messages?**

Answer (score 1):

Those are not error messages but server response status based url input. Check this.

```
resp.statusCode //if 503 or any such status codes

xhr({uri: "http://foo"},function (err, resp, body){
    if (resp.statusCode==503){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: But how do I remove those error messages from showing on the console?

Comment: This can be achieved by configuring on the web server which is serving the website or this page.